# Manipulate Properties of Model

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there a way to manipulate the properties of a Model into another property?

I need to generate the **FullName** based on the supplied **LastName** and **FirstName** properties of my Model.

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Role { get; set; } = null!;
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; } = null!; //CONCAT FROM LastName & FirstName

    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public Division Division { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `public string FullName => LastName +" "+ FirstName;`
instead of `public string FullName {get;set;}`.

Also, there really is no need to specify `= null` as a default value for reference type properties - the default value of reference types is already null.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  public string FullName
        {
            get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `FirstName` and `LastName` by making the `FullName` property getter-only:

```cs
public string LastName { get; set; };
public string FirstName { get; set; };   
public string FullName 
{
    get { return LastName + " " + FirstName; }
}
```